# Language switching is not workin in ASP.NET MVC .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to support a multi languages site which is written in .net core 3.1
the View culture switching is not being respected.  it always load the default culture. In other words goings to /en/Home/Index and /fr/Home/Index results in the same localizaion.
here is my startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opts =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("fr"), };

            opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
            opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            opts.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en"));
            }));

        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
          .AddViewLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; }).
          SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
              name: "default",
                pattern: "{culture=en}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"
                );
        });
    }
```

[image]

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization;
@using System.Globalization;
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
```

@Localizer.GetString("test")

please note I dont want to have any query parameters as our clients might of bookedmarked URLs.

I used the debugger to make sure that my program is reading /en or /fr right in ny views.

Do i need to manually do the switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting `CustomRequestCultureProvider` at the '0' position, thats mean the app will look here first to check the current culture which is always "en" in this case:

```cs
opts.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en"));
            }));
```

Either use `Add`, this will add it to the end of the providers list:

```cs
opts.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en"));
            }));
```

Or replace with:

```cs
opts.DefaultRequestculture = new RequestCulture("en");
```

Comment: I just tried this and it gives the same behaviour. i am new bie to net core, how does the framework map the languages to the culture

Comment: It seems that you didn't configure [RouteDataRequestCultureProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.localization.routing.routedatarequestcultureprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1), insert it ar '0' position of the `RequestCultureProviders` or try remove the `{culture=en}` from the route pattern to see if it works with query string parameter instead.

Comment: I ried removing it but with no luck. Actuallu it gives error 404 when i switch languages

Comment: Well, I can't really figure out what is wrong, but I recommend to read a [detailed series about localization](http://ziyad.info/en/articles/10-Developing_Multicultural_Web_Application) or [step by step tutorial for ExpressLocalization](https://medium.com/swlh/step-by-step-tutorial-to-build-multi-cultural-asp-net-core-web-app-3fac9a960c43)